# Poetry secret keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, poetry

Подскажите где хранятся  секретные ключи при использовании poetry.  .env не читает

Comment: Какая операционная система у вас?

Comment: Операционная система Ubuntu

Comment: Что за секретные ключи?

Comment: Хочу вынести ключи от амазона в отдельный файл,  типа как .env

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#configuring-credentials